# A venue booking web application should use an open source or from scratch?

Tags: php, drupal, web-applications, web, wordpress

**Project Details : My project require to have a website similar to these :**

[http://www.bookmyevent.com/][1]
[http://www.eventbrite.com/directory][2]

The above websites books events, but my web site also provide to book the Venues.

To get the development of this website, I have posted my requirements on odesk,elance etc, and found various vendors to do that.

This project is for long term, and at this time I need to make a decision :

Should this application use any open source as a base e.g. Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress or YII Framework ?

Or

Should this application develop from scratch e.g using the PHP, all self-written functions (most of them)

Is there any one can share his experience ?

Answer (score 2):

There's no right or wrong approach, it depends entirely on what you want from your app, what your budget is, how long you want to spend in development, what level of performance you want out of it.

If you want the app up and running as quickly as possible, then using systems such as Wordpress, Drupal etc are good, as you'd be able to set it up relatively quickly. The downside of course is that it won't be completely tailored to your requirements. You'd always be working within the confines of the application you chose to use.

Writing something from scratch gives you the full control that may be desired, but obviously the development times will be increased.

Given the type of app you're after, I'd suggest looking at writing something from scratch, but with a framework, so for example,

- PHP with CakePHP/CodeIgniter etc
- Ruby on Rails

Using a system such as rails for instance, allows for very rapid development times and will give you the full flexibility to do whatever you want with your app, however you want to do it. That'd be my personal choice